# Map nth index from 2d array

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

```
arr = [
  ['andrew', 'finance', 'tea', 'juice'],
  ['bob', 'finance', 'coffee', 'water'],
  ['charlie', 'sales', 'tea', 'water']
];
```

I want to return an array that looks like:

```
arr2 = [
  ['andrew', 'tea'],
  ['bob', 'coffee'],
  ['charlie', 'tea']
];
```

I have variables for the elements I want to map, like this:

```
var name = 0;
var drink = 2;
```

How do I correctly map, I was expecting something like this:

```
let arr2  = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return 
    [
        obj[name],
        obj[drink]
    ]
  
});
```

Comment: Just remove the newline between `return` and `[` (and the `let` before `arr2` or use a different name): https://jsfiddle.net/2e98x3m1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var name = 0;
var drink = 2;

const arr = [
  ['andrew', 'finance', 'tea', 'juice'],
  ['bob', 'finance', 'coffee', 'water'],
  ['charlie', 'sales', 'tea', 'water']
];


const arr2 = arr.map(e => [e[name], e[drink]]);

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = 0
var drink = 2

arr.map(elem => [elem[name], elem[drink]]) //?
```